# How to get current logged in user using django-microsoft-auth for Microsoft authentication?

Tags: python, django

I was following this guide to implement Microsoft authentication for my django app (https://django-microsoft-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) using the django-microsoft-auth package. I just don't understand how I can get the currently logged in user id/email after the user has successfully logged in as the guide does not cover this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `request.user` to get the logged in user